# A melhor forma de fazer um programa de busca de informações

Tags: python

Trabalho com produção de texto e gostaria de fazer um programa de busca que retornasse informações pré-formatadas para que eu somente copiasse e colasse no editor de texto.

Sou iniciante no Python, por isso o meu script é bem rudimentar. Fiz o seguinte:

```
_joao = 'João Silva, nascido na cidade tal, é engenheiro, ...'
_pedro = 'Pedro da Silva, nascido na cidade tal, é empresário, ...'

nome = ''
while nome != 'sair':
    def busca():
        nome = input('Digite um nome a ser buscado ou digite "sair" para fechar o programa: ')
        if nome == 'joao':
            print (_joao, '\n')
        elif nome == 'pedro':
            print (_pedro, '\n')
        elif nome == 'sair':
            exit()
        else:
            print ('Nome não encontrado')
    busca()
```

Qual a melhor forma de fazer esse tipo de programa?

Comment: A melhor forma de se programar é seguir os padrões estabelecidos pela comunidade, sua pergunta é muito abrangente, existe algum erro no código?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você não precisa definir uma função dentro do loop, ou ela será criada toda vez que repetir. A função poderia ficar fora do loop, ou então simplesmente não precisa de função nesse simples exemplo.

Uma estrutura de dados muito útil para o que você quer fazer, seria o **dicionário** - ele permite associar cada chave a um objeto - depois, permite recuperar o objeto de forma eficiente em qualquer ordem a partir da chave:

```
dados = {
    'joao': 'João Silva, nascido na cidade tal, é engenheiro, ...',
    'pedro': 'Pedro da Silva, nascido na cidade tal, é empresário, ...',
    'douglas': 'Douglas 1Alc, nascido na internet, é usuário do SOpt...',
}
```

Uma vez definido o dicionário, basta usá-lo ao invés de vários `if`s:

```
while True:
    nome = input('Digite um nome a ser buscado ou "sair" para fechar o programa')
    if nome == 'sair':
        break
    print(dados.get(nome, 'Nome nao encontrado!'))
```

No futuro, se o número de nomes aumentar muito, fica melhor usar um banco de dados como o `sqlite` para armazenar os dados, ao invés de um dicionário.

Comment: nosklo, muito obrigado pela ajuda. Está dando certo. Obg

Comment: É possível usar mais de uma chave, tipo: João, joao, JOÃO?